# Layout looks right in Editor, wrong on Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on my first Android project -- a simple one Activity app that is informational in nature. In the Android studio I have the theme setup to material light and I have my android Layout to align both TextViews to the right. Image one shows how it looks in Android Studio. However, whenever I run it in an emulator or on an Android device I get the following in Image 2. The text aligns left instead of right and the the theme changes from white to purple.

Image 1
[image: Android Studio LayOut Looks Right]

Image 2
[image: Android Emulator / Device Looks Wrong]

So... What's going on? It's a very simple app. Below is the XML for my layout for easy reference.

>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/appbg"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="8sp"
        android:text="JR's Pizza Call
        817-297-3000"
        android:textColor="#9e0f17"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTextInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/headingNumber"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:padding="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="16sp"
        android:text="For the best pizza in Crowley, Texas try JR's Pizza.  If you like pepperoni pizza, or pizza with the works, a supreme pizza, or a cheese pizza, JR's Pizza Crowley is here for you. If you like real beef hamburgers you've come to the right place. Or maybe you're in the mood for a fresh salad, pasta, or one of our delicious burritos, we have those on the menu too."
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edited my code:

> 

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headingNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:padding="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="8sp"
    android:text="JR's Pizza Call
    817-297-3000"
    android:textColor="#9e0f17"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainTextInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:layout_below="@id/headingNumber"
    android:padding="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="16sp"
    android:text="For the best pizza in Crowley, Texas try JR's Pizza.  If you like pepperoni pizza, or pizza with the works, a supreme pizza, or a cheese pizza, JR's Pizza Crowley is here for you. If you like real beef hamburgers you've come to the right place. Or maybe you're in the mood for a fresh salad, pasta, or one of our delicious burritos, we have those on the menu too."
    />
```

Comment: Do you want the grey color too or just the position of the Text.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I realize I misread what you wanted to do-  I was looking at the wrong block of text.  What android version is this?  I notice you're mixing alignParentENd and alignParentRight.  usually you'd use one or the other.  If this is a sufficiently old version of Android, that could be the problem (End didn't always exist).

Comment: @Xenolion just alignment at this point. I think I figured out how to change the theme issues in Styles.xml.

Comment: @GabeSechan This is Android Studio 3.0 with... I can't remember the API but Android 5.1.

Comment: I have added a way to change those colors in my answer you can check @JasonHolt

Comment: Okay accept the answer if it solved your question put a tick! @JasonHolt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following attribute to the `TextView` that is aligned left:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Also for the color of the `ActionBar` to look like the one in your Android Studio you can change it in the `styles.xml` folder,they are known as `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`.

Comment: Ok that works. Thank you. I also aligned the text in the view to the end of the view.